# how to block https website using squid

Tags: https, squid

I'm wondering if anybody knows how to block https websites using squid. Below is snipped configuration I have in my squid config:

```
external_acl_type my_client_bl ttl=5 negative_ttl=0 %DST %SRC /var/www/app/ACLBlacklist
acl badsites external my_client_bl
http_access deny badsites
http_access deny CONNECT badsites
```

Above configuration works with http but with https got a problem. When I block http://twitter.com, this one works but with https://twitter.com not working.

Comment: Configuration looks fine. I think that your problem is in the script ACLBlacklist. That's a script, right?

Comment: hi diegows, thanks for the reply. I don't think that is the problem. I tested it many times even in manual execution of my external program. (I wrote it using C)

Comment: i'm confuse looks like opera browser works fine with that configuration.. but firefox, chrome and other browser will go to their browser error page.  example for chrome will reply: Error 111 (net::ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED): Unknown error.

Answer (score 3):

I have carefully research this. I think the issue here when a proxy reply a forbidden 403 response from https request some browsers will allow to render html error page from proxy but unfortunately some browsers will not for some security issues (i don't get their point on this).

As of the moment and tested OPERA support forbidden 403 response from https request. Firefox, chrome, safari and IE refuse to support this.